# Select where symbol like "A%" but also some symbol is AB

Tags: mysql

suppose I have symbols `A1`, `A21`, `A567` etc, i.e. letter A with some numbers. However I also have symbols `AB1`,`AB21` etc.

When I want to select the second kind symbols, I just use:

```
select * from some_table where symbol like "AB%"
```

However if I want to select first kind symbols, I don't know how to do, since if
I use:

```
select * from some_table where symbol like "A%"
```

It will also include `AB1`, `AB21` stuff, how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another `LIKE` condition to *exclude* the terms you don't want:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE symbol LIKE "A%" AND symbol NOT LIKE 'AB%'
```

MySQL also supports regex like via the `REGEXP` operator, so we can also use this to simplify the above logic:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE symbol REGEXP 'A[0-9].*'
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: I changed the pattern from matching `A` and any number of digits, to matching `A` followed by one digit, followed by _anything_.